# Contents of ListView not showing - Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am building a `ListView` in my `MainActivity`, which contains a list of users. I initialize the `ArrayAdapter` and `ListView` using this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main_component, array);

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am filling the contents of an `ArrayList` using the following function:

```
public void usersUpdated(Message mes) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(mes.body.getField(Fields.BODY).toString());
        JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("listOfUsers");
        array = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Added : " + jsonArr.get(i).toString());
            System.out.println(jsonArr.get(i).toString().getClass().getName());
            array.add(jsonArr.get(i).toString());
        }
        System.out.println(array);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant portion of my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="332dp"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_weight="0.70" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my activity_main_component.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

The `ArrayList` is being properly filled, as the print statement just before the `runOnUiThread` in the `usersUpdated()` function is telling me. However, the `list` shows up blank. Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged in not a magic wand you need to modify underlying data.. And,  no, you didn't... You had create new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
array = new ArrayList<>();
```

You need to clear the list instead.

```
array.clear();
```

Otherwise, the Adapter loses the reference to its list

(you can also add directly to an ArrayAdapter rather than through the list; `adapter.add(String)` as well as `adapter.clear()`)

---

And also replace

```
android:id="@+id/label"
```

With

```
android:id="@android:id/text1"
```

Because this is the id that ArrayAdapter of String looks for by default

Or use this constructor

```
ArrayAdapter (Context context, 
            int resource,   // set to R.layout.activity_main_component
            int textViewResourceId,  // set to R.id.label 
            List<T> objects)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue (specifically the `array.clear()` did). Will accept this answer in 5 minutes

Comment: @Pavneet Try it. Making a new ArrayList will de-reference the one in the adapter constructor, so notifying will have no affect

Comment: @PavneetSingh as cricket_007 mentioned in his post, the Adapter loses the reference to the ArrayList that I created (which makes sense in hindsight). I did implement your solution as well, however, as I believe that it is a better practice than what I had.

Answer (score 2):

Either rename your `TextView` `id` as `android:id="@android:id/text1"` because the `adapter` will look for the `TextView` `id` as `android:id="@android:id/text1"` to set data

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

---

or you can mention `TextView` id to tell the adapter to look for the `TextView`

mention your `TextView` id while creating adapter

[`ArrayAdapter (Context context,int resource,int textViewResourceId,List<T> objects)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E))

```
   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main_component,R.id.label, array);
```

also follow the advice of @Cricket and @Selvin to complete the answer and use `array.clear()` instead of creating new `ArrayList` object

For clarity read [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)